# How to join collection in in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 collections:

collection1 is like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Tony" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614be"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Joe"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bf"), "count" : 3, "author" : "Mary" }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9314bf"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Lee" }
```

means author Tony writes 1 book, author Joe writes 2 books and author Mary writes write 3 books.

collection2 is like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Tony" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614be"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Joe"}
```

means author Tony writes 2 papers, author Joe writes 2 papers 
Collection3 is like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"),  "author" : "Tony" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614be"),  "author" : "Joe"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9624be"),  "author" : "Mary"}
```

I hope to get the author appear in collection3 and sort these authors by the number of their works：
The result is like:

```
author    number:
Joe        2 + 2 = 4
Tony       1 + 2 = 3
Mary       3 + 0 = 3
```

How can I write a single query to finish this in mongodb?

Comment: Which version of Mongo are you using?

Comment: @BanksySan version 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

This will only work in 3.2 and above.

```
db.books.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "papers",
        localField: "author",
        foreignField: "author",
        as: "papers"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$papers"  
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$author",
        bookCount: {$sum: "$count"},
        papersCount: {$sum: "$papers.count"},
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        author: "$_id",
        total: { $add: [ "$bookCount", "$papersCount"] }
    }
}])
```

Outputs:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "author" : "Tony",
    "total" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "author" : "Joe",
    "total" : 4
}
```

Comment: But I think this cannot make sure the authors are in collection3.

Comment: No, but data consistency is another job.  Mongo doesn't enforce it.  What do you want to use that third collection for?  You don't need it to do the aggregation.

Comment: For example "Joe" is not in collection3, the final result should be just {"author": "Tony", "total":3}, I hope to use collection3 filter some results.

Comment: Your question said you did want Joe.

Comment: Jo is in your authors collection in your question.

Comment: Yes, The original collection contains Joe, so Joe appears in final results. I do not give a good example at first, What I really want to is to use collection3 to filter records that are not in collection3.

Comment: You **have** to give good examples or you're wasting people's time.  To get what you want is possible, I think, but convoluted.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edit my question again, Now I add mary in collection3 and Lee in collection1. And also revise final results should be like, thank you so much